# Drupal 7 Upgrade is now causing error when editing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I upgraded 2 of my three website from Drupal to the following below:

```
Name                                           Installed Version  Proposed version  Message                   
Drupal                                         7.23               7.28              
Chaos tools (ctools)                           7.x-1.3            7.x-1.4           
Custom Search (custom_search)                  7.x-1.12           7.x-1.16          
Date (date)                                    7.x-2.6            7.x-2.7           
Devel (devel)                                  7.x-1.3            7.x-1.5           
Domain Access (domain)                         7.x-3.10           7.x-3.11          
Entity API (entity)                            7.x-1.2            7.x-1.5           SECURITY UPDATE available 
Entity Reference (entityreference)             7.x-1.0            7.x-1.1           SECURITY UPDATE available 
Field collection (field_collection)            7.x-1.0-beta5      7.x-1.0-beta7     
Google Analytics (google_analytics)            7.x-1.3            7.x-1.4           
IMCE (imce)                                    7.x-1.7            7.x-1.9           
IMCE for File Field (imce_filefield)           7.x-1.x-dev        7.x-1.0           
Link (link)                                    7.x-1.1            7.x-1.2           
Redirect 403 to User Login (r4032login)        7.x-1.5            7.x-1.7           
Scheduler (scheduler)                          7.x-1.1            7.x-1.2           
Secure Pages (securepages)                     7.x-1.0-beta1      7.x-1.0-beta2     
ShareThis (sharethis)                          7.x-2.5            7.x-2.6           
Site map (site_map)                            7.x-1.0            7.x-1.2           
Views (views)                                  7.x-3.7            7.x-3.8           
Views Bulk Operations (views_bulk_operations)  7.x-3.1            7.x-3.2           
Views Load More (views_load_more)              7.x-1.1            7.x-1.2           
Webform (webform)                              7.x-3.19           7.x-3.20
```

I can see all of my pages on my website.  when I login to edit a page I am getting the following error in my "Recent log Message" under the report section.

```
EntityMalformedException: Permission to create a node was requested but no node type was given. in entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access() (line 678 of modules/entity/modules/callbacks.inc).
```

The website page says "Error - The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

I see that there are posts about this issue that have been fixed in prior releases about 1 to 2 years ago, but I cannot find anything recent regarding a fix for this issue.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or a patch to the issue and how to apply the patch?